# Проблема с Lua циклом: убрать элементы с сохранением структуры

Tags: циклы, lua

Мне нужно из первой таблицы "a" убрать все элементы, которые написаны во второй таблице "b" НЕ МЕНЯЯ структуры первой таблицы.

```
local a = { { 'house' }, { 'car' }, { 'car' }, { 'graffiti' }, { 'house' }, { 'man' }, { 'man' } };
local b = { 'house', 'man' };
```

В итоге таблица "a" должна стать вот такой:

```
local a = { { 'car' }, { 'car' }, { 'graffiti' } };
```

Есть код, но работет неверно.

```
local a = { { 'house' }, { 'car' }, { 'car' }, { 'graffiti' }, { 'house' }, { 'man' }, { 'man' } };
local b = { 'house', 'man' };

for i, v in ipairs( a ) do
    for _, s in ipairs( b ) do
        if v[ 1 ] == s then
            table.remove( a, i )
        end
    end
end

for i, v in ipairs( a ) do
    print( v[ 1 ] )
end
```

В итоге у меня выводится

> car
>   car
>   graffiti
>   man

Долгое время ломаю голову и не могу понять, откуда взялся "man", вообще не понимаю..

Comment: Если честно, то вижу Луа впервые, но попробую угадать.

--

Возможно все дело в том, что Вы уменьшаете размер таблицы (`remove`) находясь внутри цикла по ней. Т.е. на первом проходе удалили нулевой (`house`), следующий д.б. с индексом 1 (`car`), а после удаления, он стал на самом деле нулевым и на втором проходе Вы берете уже не тот элемент.

Что-то в таком духе. Это бывает, например, в Java с итераторами.

--

Попробуйте не удалять из `a`, а строить новую (скажем `c`) только с нужными элементами, а потом замените содержимое `a` на `c`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[[@avp](/users/232/avp)](/users/232/avp) в комментарии выше абсолютно правильно вам подсказал. Вам нужно либо строить новую таблицу, либо обходить *`a`* в обратном порядке, что я и сделал ниже:

```
local a = { { 'house' }, { 'car' }, { 'car' }, { 'graffiti' }, { 'house' }, { 'man' }, { 'man' } }
local b = { 'house', 'man' }

for i = #a, 1, -1 do
    local v = a[i][1]
    for _, s in ipairs(b) do
        if v == s then
            table.remove(a, i)
        end 
    end
end

for _, v in ipairs(a) do
    print(v[1])
end
```

Comment: @Kenix Отметьте, пожалуйста, данный ответ как принятый, если он решил ваш вопрос (зелёная галочка слева от ответа).